# stylesheet_link_tag 'application' - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I have a Rails 4 app which uses Slim:

```
# application.html.slim
      = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

It throws an exception:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
  (in /Users/me/project1/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation-components.sass)
```

Even when I delete the last parameter, the error remains. How do I fix it?

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/foundation-components.sass
@import settings
@import foundation
```

The file _settings.scss exists, the file foundation.scssc only in cache.

Comment: Show your code in `project1/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation-components.sass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put your import files in quote `@import 'settings';`